# how to Bind the Values through XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am binding DataTable values to an ObservableCollection and attempting to bind the items to a ListView.

When I do the binding through XAML like: `ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"`, it doesn't display the values, but when I bind the values using C# code it displays them correctly.

I couldn't find the reason for that behavior.  Please suggest a solution ...

**In C# Code:**

```
// Declaration of the Observable Collection item.
ObservableCollection<DataTable> _observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<DataTable>();

public ObservableCollection<DataTable> Collection
{
    get { return _observableCollection; }
}
```

**Binding Data Through C# code:**

```
lstVw.ItemsSource = Collection;
```

**In XAML :**

```
<Grid>
   <ListView Name="lstVw" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Collection}" Height="auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
       <ListView.View>
          <GridView>
               <GridViewColumn  Header="OrderID" Width="auto" >
                   <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Tag="{Binding OrderID}" Content="{Binding OrderID}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                   </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               </GridViewColumn>
               <GridViewColumn Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CustomerID}" Header="CustomerID" />
               <GridViewColumn Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProductID}" Header="ProductID" />
          </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
   </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Probably the *DataContext* isn't correct.  Where/how did you set the data context of your window or control?

Comment: Actually i didn't get you word sir. here i using the itemmsSource option instead if DataContext

Comment: Your collection is in the code-behind, but you have to set a data context for the XAML, for example, in code: RootGrid.DataContext = this;

Answer (score 0):

you have two options to solve the problem, first set the DataContext to the window or user control, second use the element name at the binding.

here is the second solution

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
    x:Name="myWindow"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="640" Height="480">

  <Grid>
   <ListView Name="lstVw" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Collection, ElementName=myWindow}" Height="auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
       <ListView.View>
          <GridView>
               <GridViewColumn  Header="OrderID" Width="auto" >
                   <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Tag="{Binding OrderID}" Content="{Binding OrderID}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                   </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               </GridViewColumn>
               <GridViewColumn Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CustomerID}" Header="CustomerID" />
               <GridViewColumn Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProductID}" Header="ProductID" />
          </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
   </ListView>
  </Grid>

</Window>
```

hope this helps